# Who proved that it is possible to express any proof by using the language and notation of set theory?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, math-history, axioms

Disclaimer: Please excuse any lack of precise mathematical expression, I am just trying to wrap my head around the concepts right now.

I often read that it is possible to express and/or deduce all other mathematical theories, theorems and axioms (is this correct?) from the axioms and/or notation of set theory. Based on this, I ask myself the following questions:

- **To what extent is this true?** What is there that cannot be expressed in terms of set-theoretical notation, and is there anything that cannot be deduced using the axioms of ZFC?
- **Who exactly came to the conclusion that all this is possible?** I have read that Bertrand Russell tried to formalize and break down all of mathematics so that it can be expressed in terms of formal logic (Principia Mathematica), but I haven't found anything about a mathematician who has managed to break down all of mathematics so that it can be expressed in terms of set theory. Can someone provide me with some historical background - **how did mathematicians find out that all of mathematics can be expressed in terms of ZFC?**

Thank you very much in advance! You are helping out a high schooler in great despair.

Comment: The assertion that all of mathematics can be encoded within a set theory can be seen as a slogan rather than a mere fact - although it is possible to represent whole mathematics by using other theories like type theory, mathematicians have (maybe had - due to attempts to do mathematics over type theories) historically worked to encode mathematics into set theory, probably since Hilbert.

Comment: The ref to W&R's *Principia* is a good one: the "mathematical" axioms of *Principia*: Choice and Infinity are also axioms of $\mathsf {ZFC}$.

Answer (score 4):

> What is there that cannot be expressed in terms of set-theoretical notation?

Basically nothing : we express things using some alphabet (a set of symbols), say $\Sigma$. Any statement is hence some sequence of symbols from $\Sigma$, ie an element of $\Sigma^{< \omega}$ (often written $\Sigma^*$).

> Is there anything that cannot be deduced using the axioms of ZFC?

**Yes**, anything that is independent of ZFC, eg the continuum hypothesis.

> Who exactly came to the conclusion that all this is possible?

Nobody proved this, since *"it is possible to express any proof by using the language and notation of set theory"* is **not** a mathematical statement. Ratter, it is a meta-statement. Where would a proof of this statement take place? using which language? in which axiom system?

This thesis is well-founded, though. One can encode proofs using sets, and it seems that this encoding *mirrors* the "real" logic in the sense that one has deduction rules that empirically seem to be sound (if the code of $B$ is derived from the code of $A$ using deduction rules, then you can use it to get a proof that $A \Rightarrow B$) and complete  (if you can deduce statement $B$ from statement $A$, then the code of $B$ can be derived - within ZFC - using deduction rules from the code of $A$).